# GTA San Andreas is paused due to a hidden process running each two minutes in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

When I am playing a game like GTA San Andreas on my PC, a process runs autocratically and the game window will be minimized and the process get terminated.

This is not only when playing games, it also affects when I'm watching videos in full screen mode.

Answer (score 2):

Find the program that is stealing focus and disable it.
It could be a bad program (virus type) or it could be a good program that is just doing stupid things.
If you recentally added any cute utilities or helpers, start by disabling them and seeing if that is the problem.
Do the usual Virus scans on your system, to check for that.

In control pannel "Programs and Features" use this oppertunity to get in there and clean up anything that you installed and are not using, or that you did not install on purpose.  Some addware and garbageware will have a proper uninstall available (even if it doesn't work to uninstall it will still give you clues).

Use the program "Autoruns" to get a quick view of 3rd party additions to the system by telling it to Hide windows and microsoft items (in options).
Spend more time looking in logon ,taskscheduler and services sections.

Use the Windows resource monitor to discover what program it is:
Programs that pop in and out (often triggered by services or taskshedules) will have a delayed visual apperance in the resource monitor, showing ghosted for some time before dissapearing from the view.

Because the Disk activity section of the resource monitor shows things that happend a while ago, it also can be used to locate programs that pop in and out.

If you have no clue to which program is doing it, a possible way to find it would be to Suspend "one by one" each process in the resource monitor (and resume each before doing another).  When the undesired activity stops, find the program and disable or remove it.

Clear out your temps files, and check for files that come back quick after that. Other than some known system files.  Bad programs will often use that location to run again from.  You might locate an odd repetitive behaviour that way.

Check control pannel "Notification Area Icons" look for icons that are Not seen in the notifications tray, but are shown here.  Some programs will have used a notifications icon, and the system would pick up on that, even if they are not present at the time. Do you see anything in there that you did not install, or that should not be?